# PHP - checkbox value display in E-mail responder

Tags: php, email

I have checked all the questions first. But non of them helped to solve my problem.

I have PHP E-mail responder connected to HTML contact form. I need to display selected checkbox value inside the email responder which is sent to customer.

PHP code

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST) && ($_POST['send'] == 1)){

    $documents = array(
                    'document1' => 'http://www.example.com/document1.doc',
                    'document2' => 'http://www.example.com/document2.doc',
                    'document3' => 'http://www.example.com/document3.doc'
                    'document4' => 'http://www.example.com/document4.doc'
                );

    $to      = 'lubosmasura@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Prihláška na školenie';
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $document = implode(", ",$post['document']);
    
    

    if(isset($_POST['document']) && count($_POST['document']) > 0){
        foreach($_POST['document'] as $doc){
            if(isset($documents[$doc])){
             $document = implode(", ",$post['document']);
             $message = "
             ŠKOLENIE: $document
             ";
        }
        }
    }


    $headers = 'From: noreply@marcelaskolenia.sk' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: noreply@marcelaskolenia.sk' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   }
   ?>
```

HTML code

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    
                            <p class="center">Vyberte školenie</p>
                            <label class="container riadok"><p for="document" class="dolava">§20 Poučená osoba</p>
                            <input type="checkbox"  name="document[]" value="document1" id="document">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                            <label class="container riadok"><p for="document" class="dolava">Aktualizácia: §21 AŽ §24</p>
                            <input type="checkbox"  name="document[]" value="document2" id="document">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                            <label class="container riadok"><p for="document" class="dolava">§21 Elektrotechnik</p>
                            <input type="checkbox"  name="document[]" value="document3" id="document">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                            <label class="container riadok"><p for="document" class="dolava">§24 Revízny technik</p>
                            <input type="checkbox"  name="document[]" value="document4" id="document">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                            <p class="center">Vyplňte osobné údaje</p>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Meno">
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                            <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefónne číslo" pattern="[0-9]+"  title="Zadajte iba čísla." required="required">
                            
<input type="hidden" name="send" value="1" />
 <button type="submit" value="SEND" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> ODOSLAŤ PRIHLÁŠKU</button>
```

Email responder works but it does not display selected checkbox value from HTML form behaind message ŠKOLENIE: **CHECKBOX HERE**

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: You have 4 different check boxes for document, but only 3 documents in your array... just for starters.

Comment: @StatikStasis yes, I know this, but those documents are just for attachments, they are not modified yet. But thank you anyway :)

Comment: @StatikStasis edited ;)

Comment: If this part is true, if(isset($_POST['document'])  , this part, if(isset($documents[$doc])) , should already be true and no need to check if it isset.

Comment: This, $document = implode(", ",$post['document']), should be, $document = implode(", ",$doc)

Comment: @StatikStasis probably that did the thing, hold on let me check the HTML value, because now I have some value there, one sec.

Comment: Also, you forgot a </form> tag

Comment: It did not get copied, my bad. It is there. Put your POST answer as the right answer so I could give you checkmark.

Comment: Glad it worked. Solution posted as described in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
if(isset($_POST['document']) && count($_POST['document']) > 0) {
    foreach($_POST['document'] as $doc){
        if(isset($documents[$doc])){
            $document = implode(", ",$_POST['document']);
            $message = "
            ŠKOLENIE: $document
            ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to display even a label instead of value by adding any array translation?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have such a variable as `$post`, but you try to use it twice. Replace it with `$_POST` and your form will work.

This:

```
$document = implode(", ",$post['document']);
```

Replace with this:

```
$document = implode(", ",$_POST['document']);
```

And it should work.

Some hints:

1. Properly configured IDE will let you know about such errors as an undeclared variable. Use PHPStorm (commercial) or VSCode (free).
2. Don't close php tag (?>) at the end of your file (PSR2):

> The closing ?> tag MUST be omitted from files containing only PHP.

3. Don't use the same identifier (id) multiple times. The id should be unique in the entire HTML document.

Edit: // As someone has mentioned in the comments, you don't have a closing tag for `<form>` tag, but I assumed that you pasted only a part of your HTML document. Otherwise, you should correct that as well.

Comment: only newbies are using IDEs :) it is much better to learn in some normal text editor ... often you have to change something on the fly via SSH etc, you don't have computer with you etc etc.

Comment: Coding in a text editor and deployment via SSH? It's not 2010 anymore :)

Comment: In 2010 there were IDEs as well. If you can't code in mc or editplus, you are not a real programmer. Suggesting others to use IDEs is a bad idea in my opinion.

Comment: is there any way to display even a label instead of value by adding any array translation?

Comment: @LuboMasura not sure what you mean ... label is not being sent in the `$_POST`

Comment: I mean that now I see value right? It works fantastic, but If I want to see label instead of value of the checkbox how could I do this?

Comment: You can change your `document[]` to `document[0]`, `document[1]` etc ... in the HTML code and then map these values on PHP by that value

Comment: Yes I understand but how about if I want to use some latin extended labels like školenie etc. it is not supported by the values but by the labels, how do I translate value into label in php?

Comment: @FlashThunder. Using suboptimal tools doesn't make you a better programmer. And changing anything in a production software bypassing deployment pipeline is a really bad idea.

Comment: IDEs are not optimal and are making you handicapped when you are lack of your computer, been there with my subordinates, nightmare

Comment: @LuboMasura in PHP ... when you got your value, you can make array like `$translated => array(0 => 'latin something', 1 => 'latin something different');` and then use them in PHP instead of values like `echo $translated[0]`, you have to ask another question for a full code

Comment: Can not post 40 minutes, its limited for 90 min per question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63853220/php-display-checkbox-label-instead-of-its-value @FlashThunder