# PHP - Display checkbox label instead of its value in E-mail

Tags: php, email

Any idea how could I show the checkbox label instead of value in my PHP Email responder? My E-mail responder displays only checkbox value instead of label. I need to implement document translation arrays for each label.

PHP code

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST) && ($_POST['send'] == 1)){

    $documents = array(
                    'document1' => 'http://www.example.com/document1.doc',
                    'document2' => 'http://www.example.com/document2.doc',
                    'document3' => 'http://www.example.com/document3.doc'
                    'document4' => 'http://www.example.com/document4.doc'
                );

    $to      = 'lubosmasura@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Prihláška na školenie';
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $document = implode(", ",$POST['document']);
    
    

    if(isset($_POST['document']) && count($_POST['document']) > 0){
        foreach($_POST['document'] as $doc){
            if(isset($documents[$doc])){
            
             $message = "
             ŠKOLENIE: $document
             ";
        }
        }
    }


    $headers = 'From: noreply@marcelaskolenia.sk' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: noreply@marcelaskolenia.sk' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   }
   ?>
```

HTML code

```
  <form method="post" action="test.php">
    
    <p class="center">Vyberte školenie</p>
    <label  class="container riadok"><p for="document1" class="dolava">§20 Poučená osoba</p>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="document[]" value="document1" id="document1">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container riadok"><p for="document" class="dolava">Aktualizácia: §21 AŽ §24</p>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="document[]" value="document2" id="document2">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container riadok"><p for="document" class="dolava">§21 Elektrotechnik</p>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="document[]" value="document3" id="document3">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container riadok"><p for="document" class="dolava">§24 Revízny technik</p>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="document[]" value="document4" id="document4">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <p class="center">Vyplňte osobné údaje</p>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Meno">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefónne číslo" pattern="[0-9]+"  title="Zadajte iba čísla." required="required">
                            
<input type="hidden" name="send" value="1" />
 <button type="submit" value="SEND" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> ODOSLAŤ PRIHLÁŠKU</button>
</form>
```

Email responder works but it does not display selected checkbox label but only value from HTML ŠKOLENIE: **CHECKBOX LABEL HERE**

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Display `$documents[$doc]` instead of `$document`

Comment: it gives me URL adress from array @Barmar

Comment: What do you want instead?

Comment: Label @Barmar for example document1 = url and label for it is Hello, then I want to display hello

Comment: Do you mean the contents of the `<label>` element?

Comment: Labels aren't sent in form submissions.

Comment: Is there any chance to set array for URL and gives it any name and display only name? @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    
    <p class="center">Vyberte školenie</p>
    <label  class="container riadok"><p for="document1" class="dolava">§20 Poučená osoba</p>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="document[1]" value="document1" id="document1">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container riadok"><p for="document" class="dolava">Aktualizácia: §21 AŽ §24</p>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="document[2]" value="document2" id="document2">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container riadok"><p for="document" class="dolava">§21 Elektrotechnik</p>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="document[3]" value="document3" id="document3">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container riadok"><p for="document" class="dolava">§24 Revízny technik</p>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="document[4]" value="document4" id="document4">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <p class="center">Vyplňte osobné údaje</p>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Meno">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefónne číslo" pattern="[0-9]+"  title="Zadajte iba čísla." required="required">
                            
<input type="hidden" name="send" value="1" />
 <button type="submit" value="SEND" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> ODOSLAŤ PRIHLÁŠKU</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
   $translation_table = array(1 => '§20 Poučená osoba', 2 => 'Aktualizácia: §21 AŽ §24'); // fill it yourself, I am not going to do that, just add another numbers and labels
   if(isset($_POST['document'])){
      foreach($_POST['document'] as $id => $val){
         echo $translation_table[$id] . " = " . $val . "<br />";
      }
   }
?>
```

That should help you in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Labels aren't sent automatically in form submissions.

You could change your HTML so you include the label in the checkbox value.

```
    <label  class="container riadok"><p for="document1" class="dolava">§20 Poučená osoba</p>
    <input type="checkbox"  name="document[document1]" value="§20 Poučená osoba<" id="document1">
```

Then in PHP you do:

```
foreach ($documents as $key => $label) {
    if (isset($documents[$key])) {
        $message = "ŠKOLENIE: $label";
    }
}
```

Also, you're overwriting `$message` each time through the loop. You should be appending to it, not replacing it.

```
    $message .= "
        ŠKOLENIE: $label
        ";
```

Comment: empty mail returns back